# send message with sockets

Tags: angularjs, sockets

I just need to have a user send private message to another user.

I have a service in angular with methods:

```
     onSend:function(data) {
       socket.emit('notification:save', {
       message:'fromClient'
       });
       console.log("emittted")
      },
      onReceive:function(){
        socket.on('notification:save',function(message){
          console.log("recieved notif on mesage send")
        })
        console.log("recieved")
      }
```

controller:

```
if(Auth.isLoggedIn()){
     socket.onReceive();
  }

$scope.sendMessage  = function () {
      socket.onSend($scope.message.newMessage);
      $scope.message.newMessage = '';
    };
```

1. It emits the event when I call `$scope.sendMessage`  function but never is able to listen to the event i.e `onReceive` is never triggered.
2. How do I make this adapt to send to a particular client?
3. I need to listen and emit event both at front end. Just a notification so nothing that I need to store in db. Do I still have to include server side in this part of `emit` and `on` for events.

Comment: is this socket.io? if so you need a server to broker the communication between multiple clients. each client would make a connection to the socket io server which should store the connection with a client id, and then you can use rooms or socket ids to send messages directly to other clients through the server. The server code would determine what socket to send the message to.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mind directing me to a neat example for private messaging? I just can not find one that I understand. @vbranden

Comment: you can just start with the basic chat example on the socket.io page since you are essentially trying to create a private chat. http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: see my working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of a private message server using socket.io. this uses nodejs and express on the server side, jquery on the client and socketio on both. the client.html is for demonstration only. in angular you would supply the username before connection to the socket.io server. in client.html you will need to enter it in the username field then click connect on both clients before sending messages. to test you can use 2 different browsers (ie. firefox for 1 client, chrome for another) make sure the user name is different on each client otherwise you will be sending messages to yourself.

**server.js**

```
var app        = require('express')();
var http       = require('http').Server(app);
var io         = require('socket.io')(http);
var _          = require('lodash');
var clients    = {};


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('<h1>Message Server</h1>');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

    // store the socket with the username if a reply event was emitted
    socket.on('reply.username', function(username) {
        console.log('Got Username reply', username);
        clients[username] = socket;
    });

    // handle direct messages
    socket.on('msg.private', function(obj) {
        console.log('routing private message');
        if (obj.to && clients[obj.to]) {
            console.log('delivering to', obj.to);
            clients[obj.to].emit('msg.private', obj.message);
        }
    });

    // emit a request to the client to send its username back
    socket.emit('send.username');
});


//start the server
http.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Started server');
});
```

**client.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>

    var socket;

    function connectIO() {
        socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');

        socket.on('send.username', function() {
            console.log('Server requested username');
            socket.emit('reply.username', $('#username').val());
        });

        // recieve a message
        socket.on('msg.private', function(msg) {
            $('#chat').html(msg);
        });
    }

    // send the pm
    function sendPM() {
        socket.emit('msg.private', {
            to: $('#to').val(),
            message: $('#msg').val()
        });
        $('#message').val('');
    }

</script>
<form>
    <textarea id="chat" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea><br>
    Username: <input type="text" id="username"><br>
    To: <input type="text" id="to"><br>
    Message: <input type="text" id="msg"><br>
    <span onclick="sendPM()">Send</span><br>
    <span onclick="connectIO()">Connect</span>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```